# Solidjs Stripe pricing table undefined client-reference-id

Tags: stripe-payments, web-component, solid-js

I'm trying to use [stripe embbed pricing table](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pricing-table#handle-fulfillment-with-the-stripe-api) with solid.js

I've defined a simple component:

```js
import { Show } from "solid-js";

import type { ComponentProps } from "solid-js";

declare module "solid-js" {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      "stripe-pricing-table": ComponentProps<"div"> & {
        "client-reference-id": string;
        "pricing-table-id": string;
        "publishable-key": string;
      };
    }
  }
}

export default function PricingPage({ customer }: { customer: string }) {
  return (
    <Show when={customer} fallback={<p>Error</p>}>
      {
        <stripe-pricing-table
          client-reference-id={customer}
          pricing-table-id="id"
          publishable-key="key"
        ></stripe-pricing-table>
      }
    </Show>
  );
}
```

However, the `client_reference_id` I received from the webhook is always undefined. I obviously checked before that `customer` is defined and is a valid Stripe `client-reference-id`.

I think that the issue comes from the dynamic `client-reference-id` prop itself.

I tested different things, `client-reference-id="test"` returns me the valid `client-reference-id` in the webhook however`client-reference-id={"test"}` returns me null.

I already tried to use `h` or `html`.

This is how I called my component:

```js
<PricingPage customer="testcustomer" />
```

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the code where you're rendering PricingPage? When/where are you checking that `customer` is defined?

Comment: @karbi , Hi, I've updated my post to show how I called my PricingPage component, however even when I send 'hard-coded' customer props like in the example, it doesn't work so I don't think it is the problem here. It think it's more related to solid-js

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a signal for `customer` value, any updates to its value will not be reflected because of the destructuring assignment in `PricingPage`.

By descructuring props, you will be creating a local variable hence destroying reactivity and stuck with the default value. Solid conveys reactivity between components via function calls. So, you should be using accessing `customer` via props like `props.customer`

Another problem with your component is you have unnecessary expression wrapper around `stripe-pricing-table`. If it is a valid element, you can use it directly.

Lastly, Solid's built-in `Component` generic provides better clarity when declaring a component.

So, in overall your component should be like as follows:

```js
export const PricingPage: Component<{ customer: string }> = (props) => {
  return (
    <Show when={props.customer} fallback={<p>Error</p>}>
      <stripe-pricing-table
        client-reference-id={props.customer}
        pricing-table-id="id"
        publishable-key="key"
      />
    </Show>
  );
}
```

If this does not solve your problem, you need to make sure your Stripe API setup works and then you need to fix how you store and access client reference id. Solidjs does not use VDOM, and compiles into native DOM nodes. So, you need to use a signal for values changing over time.

If you make remote API calls to get the client ID, then use a reasource: https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest/api#createresource.

I'm not familiar with Stripe API but it does not hurt using more distinctive and descriptive names for table ids and keys.